# What size of intraclass correlation coefficient or design effect indicates clustering can be ignored?

Tags: mixed-model, intraclass-correlation

I am working on a project where people are clustered into "agencies".  Because there are a lot of other complications to the design, I would like to ignore the clustering.  I found one relatively old reference from Muthen in *Sociological Methodology* that said it can be ignored if the "design effect" is less than 2 where

$$\text{DE} = 1 + (\text{average cluster size} - 1)\text{ICC}$$

but I'd like confirmation from any other source.

EDIT: The other complications are substantial missing data that I plan to multiply impute and that I need to test mediation models.

Comment: You can check this [link](http://unstats.un.org/unsd/publication/seriesy/seriesy_10e.pdf) page 100 or this [one](http://www.journalslibrary.nihr.ac.uk/__data/assets/pdf_file/0008/64853/FullReport-hta3050.pdf) page 22.

Comment: Thanks.  Those are useful but, unless I am missing something, neither directly answers my question about how low an ICC or design effect should be to make a multilevel model unnecessary.

Comment: I think that this is case depending. How I have been instructed and educated is to use a derivative of the average cluster size and choose the "elbow", where increasing the number of clusters/decreasing the average size of clusters does not improve the solution "enough", which is often. The other way I sometimes use are the information criterion. If this does not produce "satisfactory" results then the clustering can be dropped. I acknowledge the sketchiness of this, but what ever works is the non-academic way of data-analysis. The disciplines have their own good practices and rules of thumbs.

Comment: Perhaps I am being a bit stupid here but how will you know your ICC and hence DE until you have done the analysis?

Comment: You can find ICC from a very simple MLM and then, if the design effect is small, do a "regular" analysis.  At least, that's what I think, based on reading Muthen in Soc. Methods.

Comment: Even if the ICC is large based on an intercept-only MLM, it might become trivially small when you include relevant predictors in the model and thus would indicate a MLM isn't really necessary with the full model specification. Can you provide some additional details regarding the other complications in the design?

Comment: The other complications are that there is missing data which I plan to multiply impute and that I need to test mediation models.